# Regex to capture alpha numeric before pipe separated

Tags: regex

I've been trying to create a regex with space & alpha numeric values.

Below Im sharing the sample String.

```
Manchester United 8547|12345678910
                      |12345678910
Manchester            |12345678910
124587933             |12345678910
8457 Manchester United|12345678910
     Manchester United|12345678910
```

I want to capture everything before pipe(|) separated. At times there is a possibility of complete space and no alpha numeric values before pipe(|) which I've shown in 2nd example. Regex should not capture pipe(|) and next numerical values(12345678910).

I've tried below regex but none are working for me.

```
^.*$
^[\s\w\d]+$
[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+
[a-zA-Z0-9\s\W]+
^[\sa-z|A-Z|0-9]+$
^[\sa-z|A-Z|0-9]+$
[^\s]*$
([^\"]*)
^[a-zA-Z0-9]$
^([^?]*)$
.+?(?=\w)
\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+
^[\sa-zA-Z0-9]+
```

**I need a full match & not group match**

for example if I try for

Manchester 8457 then regex would be `Manchester \d+`. This gives me full match & not group match.

Comment: (.*?)\|.*

I think above you are looking for, then group1 will give anything before pipe. 


Please see  https://regex101.com/r/EElTwz/1

Comment: I want a full match and this ain't working for me

Comment: probably all you need to do is implement @Kmandal's comment you can just split it with new line character & then apply the regex on each of the separated strings.

Comment: string.substring(0,string.indexOf("|"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match alphanumeric before the pipe and not get a group match, but a match only, you can use a character class with a positive lookahead `(?=\|)` (if that is supported) to assert the pipe at the right.

```
^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+(?=\|)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP8UEH/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
input.substring(0,input.indexOf("|"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every line would have a pipe, you could split the input string on CRLF, and then extract the portion to the left of the pipe:

```
String input = "Manchester United 8547|12345678910\n                      |12345678910\nManchester            |12345678910\n124587933             |12345678910\n8457 Manchester United|12345678910\n     Manchester United|12345678910\n";
String[] parts = input.split("\r?\n");
List<String> contents = Arrays.stream(parts)
    .map(x -> x.split("\\|")[0].trim())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(contents);
```

This prints:

```
[Manchester United 8547, , Manchester, 124587933, 8457 Manchester United,
 Manchester United]
```

Answer (score 0):

for getting alphanumeric part use the following

> ^\s*\w(.+?)\|

This should answer your question i guess.

[image]

> ^(.+?)\|

Please use this and try it checks only for the beginning string.[image]

its is for the pipe

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/180)

Comment: Edited my question please check